# В Microsof SQL cоздал временную таблицу загрузил в нее данные. а вот как теперь из временной загрузить в другую таблицу не могу разобраться

Tags: sql-server

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#tesin') is not null drop table #tesin
create table #tesin (
ID varchar(100) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
F49 varchar(100) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
F50 varchar(100) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
F51 varchar(100) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
F52 varchar(100) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
F53 varchar(100) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
F54 varchar(100) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
F55 varchar(100) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
F56 varchar(100) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
F241 varchar(100) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
F242 varchar(100) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
F603 varchar(100) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
F604 varchar(100) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL
);
SELECT
l.ID,
l.F49,
l.F50,
l.F51,
l.F52,
l.F53,
l.F54,
l.F55,
l.F56,
l.F241,
l.F242,
l.F603,
l.F604
FROM
deltaCollection.dbo.loans l
WHERE
l.Stage = 19
INSERT
INTO
deltaCollection.ImportGateway.[Index]
SELECT
l.ID,
l.F49,
l.F50,
l.F51,
l.F52,
l.F53,
l.F54,
l.F55,
l.F56,
l.F241,
l.F242,
l.F603,
l.F604
FROM
#tesin l
```

Comment: что такое у вас deltaCollection.ImportGateway.[Index] ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: deltaCollection.ImportGateway - путь к таблицы, Index - сама таблица

Comment: Данные из таблица Loans выгружаются во временную таблицу #tesin, а потом из временной таблицы нужно загрузить в таблицу Index, выгрузить данные у меня получилось а вот загрузить не как.

Comment: и какая ошибка при выполнении INSERT? у вас есть доступ к схеме ImportGateway?

Answer (score 0):

Не известно какие поля в таблице Index, поэтому в инсерте возможно их надо будет поправить.
Такой запрос должен был бы отработать нормально:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#tesin') is not null drop table #tesin
-- Загрузка во временную таблицу из loans
SELECT l.ID, l.F49, l.F50, l.F51, l.F52, l.F53, l.F54, l.F55, l.F56, l.F241, l.F242, l.F603, l.F604
INTO #tesin
FROM deltaCollection.dbo.loans l
WHERE l.Stage = 19
-- Загрузка в таблицу Index из временной
INSERT INTO deltaCollection.ImportGateway.[Index]
(ID, F49, F50, F51, F52, F53, F54, F55, F56, F241, F242, F603, F604)
SELECT l.ID, l.F49, l.F50, l.F51, l.F52, l.F53, l.F54, l.F55, l.F56, l.F241, l.F242, l.F603, l.F604
FROM #tesin l
```